# Fontawesome `fa-bars` change style: width, thin, distance

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

How reduce the thickness of the fontawesome `fa-bars` and increase the distance between the vertical lines and extend the horizontal lines?

```
 <i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

.fa {
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Font Awesome icons are in fact Unicode characters, so you affect the main "drawing" by tinkering with the element's text properties. In your case, `font-weight: light;`. Also, I don't suppose you want to apply this change to every Font Awesome character by assigning it to the `.fa` class, or every `bars` character, by assigning it to the `.fa-bars` class. Put a id on this element, then assign it just to the id `#bars`, for example.

Comment: You would need to purchase pro version of Font Awesome to achieve what you want. As you can see [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars?style=light), thinner bars are available only on pro version.

Comment: @LucasArbex yeah, since the "drawing" is a single, standalone character, you can affect its text properties, like color, weight, size, etc, but not the "drawing" itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something that is more customizable like:

```css
.bars div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bars">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

This way you can edit the thickness and eventually add customizations like animations.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my comment, take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tiramonium/g3a0hxc2/1/).

```css
#bars {
  color: black;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i id="bars" class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```